# How to create template type of enum

Tags: c++

```
enum MyEnum{
  task1 = 0,
  task2 
};

// template<MyEnum T>  works
template<class T>
void fun(){

}


int main(){
 fun<MyEnum::task1>();
//  fun<int>(); works
}
```

How to create template type of enum

When I try to create a template out of enum I get error saying no matching function for call to ‘fun()

Why does the int work by not enum type?

When I do `template<MyEnum T>` it works but I dont understand why.

Comment: `MyEnum::task1` is a value.  `MyEnum` is a type

Comment: Why does doing  `template<MyEnum T> ` works then?

Comment: Because then you aren't asking for a type, you're asking for a value.  If you have `typename` or `class` you are asking for a type.  If you have a type, then you are asking for a value.

Comment: @mato `template<MyEnum T>` is a [non-type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters).  Similar to `template<int I>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the int work by not enum type?

It *does* work for `enum` type just like it does for `int` type.

Just like `fun<int>();` works, `fun<MyEnum>();` works

---

And just like `fun<1>();` doesn't work, `fun<MyEnum::task1>();` doesn't work.

---

To make it work for values, like `1` or `MyEnum::task1`, you need to declare the template parameter differently, e.g.

```
template<int v>
```

or

```
template<MyEnum v>
```